Physically/fundamentally/literally, why does a significant voltage not develop across a diode in forward bias?
I am asking for a fundamental and physical explanation of why, not formulas.
Let's take an ideal diode. Let's say I have some voltage source not big enough to breakdown and destroy the diode, but much larger than its threshold voltage of .7 V; whether this is a good value or not, let's say 5 V.
I have this 5 V AC source in series with a diode in forward bias and no other circuit components.
Physically, what is stopping the full 5 V from developing across the diode in forward bias but in not reverse bias?
I am thinking of the ideal diode graph where during the positive half of the cycle the voltage is Vd (0.7 V) and during the negative half -5 V. I can't understand or find a reason for this.
Most of the answers are that the current limits the voltage or that after 0.7 V there is no more ability for the diode to develop more than 0.7 V drop.
Why is it able to in reverse bias but not forward bias?
After I apply so much voltage beyond 0.7V, the resistance drops so more current flows, which doesn't seem to make sense to me.
Somehow in forward bias, this device magically limits the voltage to some threshold, but also if I apply more voltage the resistance keeps dropping to allow more current. I have to be missing something here. I want to understand the actual why. A lot of analogies were to that of a valve, it only has an opening so big, so more pressure (voltage) will cause more water (current) to flow through. I still just don't get how the voltage is self limited like this.

"Let's take an ideal resistor."  Did you mean "Let's take an ideal diode" ?

See my comparison of an ideal resistor and ideal diode to see the real diode.

You can't push hard on a string.

Get a grip on how semiconductors work by the exponential field equations and thermal reasons why you can't sustain much more than 1V so 0.7 is for a comfortable usage level that won't burn your fingers.  Don't try to equate it with magic or a water valve.

Do you understand now how a diode works? Your feedback is needed?

Ok, you're tricking yourself here! Things aren't as confusing as they seem.
You're just trying to combine two "ideal" things, which don't exist, but whose "idealness" assumptions are mutually exclusive. So, you're using two models that cannot be combined, and as soon as you stop using an "ideal diode" with an "ideal voltage source", things start working as you'd expect them to.
Your "ideal diode" can, in the presence of an external voltage greater than its threshold, conduct infinite current without the voltage across it increasing, meaning it can bring any real-world voltage source (yes, a nuclear power plant) to its knees, in the sense that even with the smallest > 0 source resistance, the voltage drops. That's the "mechanism" with which the voltage across the diode gets "capped" to 0.7 V.
An ideal voltage source can source infinite current without dropping voltage.
So, both don't exist, they are just "useful" models as long as you don't combine the ideal diode with something that can either source infinite current or combine the ideal voltage source with something that can conduct infinite current without increasing voltage.
But you try to combine these two simplifying models, and that fails, as you notice.
So, what happens here is that you apply a model outside of its range of applicable conditions. That's all.
In reality, diodes aren't ideal. You let 1 A run through a (relatively big) diode, you might see 0.7 V across it. You let 10 A run through, you might see 0.75 V across it. You let 100 A run through, you might seem 0.78 V across it. Not linear, and very low "differential resistance", i.e., increasing current increase voltage across the diode only very slightly, but it does increase the voltage.
So, suddenly, your ideal voltage source isn't driving something whose voltage drop stays constant regardless of current anymore.
And the same for the series resistance of your voltage source: the ideal voltage source has 0 Ω, and doesn't exist. Your wall outlet might have 0.5 Ω, as an order of magnitude: If you have 230 V AC on an unloaded outlet, if you attach a 3.7 kW room heater, which is really just a large 14.375Ω resistor, then a current of roughly 16 A flows, but the voltage drops to 222 V.
If you attach a 40 W lightbulb, the voltage drop of your outlet will be practically impossible to measure, so saying "hey, for things that aren't huge room heaters, the approximation that the power grid up to my outlet is an ideal AC voltage source" holds. But attache something large, and the model doesn't hold anymore.
The ideal diode would be an energy black hole. It could swallow all the current you put in without having more than 0.7 V across it. That also doesn't exist, but attaching it to a real outlet would immediately make the positive half of the 230 V AC cycle be clipped to 0.7 V.
In reality, of course, your diode would immediately go up in a puff of smoke, milliseconds after you measured that indeed, for a very short time, it was able to conduct a lot of current, but not infinitely much, indeed making the internal resistance of the outlet drop the voltage to something slightly above 0.7 V.

Figure 1 from this 100A diode shows the progression of voltage/current relation as you describe. The diagram added here may be helpful to future readers.
https://mm.digikey.com/Volume0/opasdata/d220001/medias/docus/5010/1N3288-1N3297.pdf

To tl;dr this great answer: the OP accidentally discovered the reason mathematicians avoid defining a value for $\frac00$.

There seems to be no specs for "ideal"; This makes the question and yours and similar answers invalid. Does it look like a hockey stick, a right angle plot or the ideal Shockley equation.

@D.A.S. there is. "ideal diode" and "ideal voltage source" are pretty universally agreed on to deal with ability to deal with infinite currents with no current drop.

I disagree that "ideal diode" is a 0.7V drop as stated. It is either 0V in the primitive view or near 0V in the FET implementation with polarity control. or the Shockley equation in the theoretical view of the ideal exponential diode characteristics with no limits.   Am I the only one to see that this misrepresents what ideal means due to a poorly phrased assumption? 0.7V is just a common threshold above 1mA and well below it's rated current. It distorts the reality of how it works. Unless it is for entertainment value of discussing singularities.

@D.A.S. you'll notice that the 0.7 V is irrelevant to what the problem was that OP had. So, yes, you seem to be the only one seeing that problem; the question OP asks is about these singularities. So the right thing to do is to discuss the singularities

Yet this lacks the feedback to confirm your assumptions. How did that explain reverse bias leakage which is directly inverse with ideal forward current not even get a mention for a reality check.

@D.A.S. I'm sorry. reverse leakage is completely out of scope for the question and atop of that completely irrelevant to the reason that the question was asked. Focus! The question was, as stated: *I take a component that I call the "ideal diode", which has the property "forward voltage always 0.7V when externally applied voltage >= 0.7 V. How can that be? my voltage source can deliver voltages > 0.7 V". Nothing there is concerned about reverse behaviour.

@MarcusMüller "Why is it able to (be) in reverse bias but not forward bias?"begs the answer to why are these are different but related to the ideal diode law and the current in each direction determines the voltage. But instead false assumptions about "always 0.7" and ignoring the reality of bulk resistance Rd~=k/Pmax  explains perfectly why the current is not infinite from Vf but becomes almost a  linear resistor after 0,7V.

@richard1941 when you closely read OP's question, you'll notice that their "ideal diode" really can, else they'd not be asking this question.

If you put a diode across an ideal 5 V AC source, there will indeed be 5 V across the diode, and extremely high current (at least until the diode melts).

And after the diode melts, there will still be 5V across it. . . But the current will be much less.

The ideal diode cannot melt as it has zero power dissipation! Also, the wires are superconductors, which will let infinite current pass through it...

@15Volts You'll note that I claimed only the source was ideal, not the diode.

A diode is a PN junction, two materials that normally won't conduct that much but have free charge carriers that can be persuaded to move about if a big enough electric potential is applied.
The material in a diode will initially (for a small voltage) not move around/re-arrange much, but as the voltage across it increases the electrons and holes-where-electrons-could-be all get attracted to the electric field provided by the voltage you have applied to it's terminals.
So for a low voltage not much will happen, the charge carriers will get pulled about a bit, maybe a bit of current will flow.
At a certain point the voltage you have applied to the terminals is more than enough to drag (or push) all the charge carries really close to a point where they are close enough to start interacting  with each other as much as they want.
At this point the junction couldn't be any more conductive (I don't mean a superconductor, just it's as conductive as it's possible for this junction to be), the voltage you applied has pushed the internal diode regions to the point where they are as combined as they will get. As you increase voltage at this point all you are doing is applying a large voltage accross a very low (because the junction has been pushed together as much as possible) resistance, so as you increase voltage the current just keeps getting bigger until it burns out the device.
The 'literally why' answer is that after a certain voltage applied the two physical junctions have been squished together about as much as they can be, and any further incease in voltage just increases current flow. It's a physcial process.
This is why the analogy of a valve kind of half works, a valve needs a certain pressure to open (voltage in the case of a diode), once it is fuly open there is nothing resisting any further flow, you can pump as much into it as you want until you meet the limit of the what the pipes (or the diode itself) can pass without damaging something.

As to ‘literally why’ there is such a thing as forward and reverse bias in a diode, try here: https://theengineeringmindset.com/the-basics-of-diodes-explained/
The short explanation: the different doping in P and N material cause electrostatic forces at the diode PN junction to form a depletion region, a barrier that requires voltage to overcome.
As the diode enters forward bias, the applied voltage opposes those forces. As the forward voltage increases, the  depletion region shrinks down until it disappears, allowing electrons to move directly from N to P.
In reverse bias, the applied voltage adds to the electrostatic forces, making the depletion region grow even larger, further blocking the flow. It will continue to do this with further increases in reverse voltage until reverse breakdown is reached.
The case you describe, applying an ideal 5V AC source across an ideal diode (or at least a simple model of one), would result in infinite current. Which is not known to be possible in our physical world.
(There is some investigation of superconducting diodes which get closer to it.)
A real voltage source has resistance. So does the diode: the resistance of the bulk semiconducting material, terminals, leads, etc.; and of the PN junction itself.
What will happen is that once the forward voltage threshold is met, there will be a steep (but not vertical) increase in current, and small increase in forward voltage. It will behave essentially like a wire with a fixed voltage in series with a small resistance.
With enough current forced through it, over a long enough time, the diode will eventually fail. Or, the voltage source resistance will limit the current. One way or another, something's gotta give.

The Shockley ideal diode equation states that the Vf forward voltage rises about 120 mV for every decade of a tiny current starting on the order of 1e-9 A or one nanoamp to exceed the barrier threshold.   Special materials are injected into 99.999% Silicon of opposite charge polarity so that the junction sees a very high electric field or e-field which causes very different behaviours in opposite polarity.  From a large scale, it looks like an imperfect polarized switch.  Not only does it follow this logarithmic behaviour in the forward direction, but its resistance also drops with a rising current in the same manner which permits many different applications such as low-power RF detectors and high-power line rectifiers.
Near rated current levels, the incremental resistance cannot go any lower than the bulk resistance of the junction, which depends on the size and power dissipation rating of the diode**. Thus, the minimum resistance can be predicted from the power rating. But the power dissipated should never be operated near its maximum temperature of 150 'C as a Chemistry equation (Arrhenius effect) dictates that failure rates double every 10 'C rise above room temperature.
Because power is the product of voltage and current, a common average forward voltage is 0.7V for cooler operation. When operating near max. power, the voltage can rise near 1V.    Because this e-field exponentially allows more current with a small linear voltage, for Silicon it gets limited by the maximum temperature of the diode.  For this reason the voltage drop has a practical limit.
Here I compare two very old common diodes rated for 0.1 and 1A are shown below rectifying different tungsten bulbs with the RMS current and average Watts shown for each part.
Let's see if you observe some things in common with peak diode voltage and power dissipation of same.  The Voltage source supplies power, so it is negative.  You will get 1 point for every good observation.


For giggles if you wanted to see a bigger diode that can handle large currents;  The lesson to learn is that the ideal diode becomes a low value bulk resistor above the "threshold" voltage and is related to the maximum power the part can dissipate. Source: https://www.mccsemi.com/pdf/Products/DZW10500(W2).pdf

Rd or rT=k/Pmax for all diodes and k=0.25 to 1 is the nominal design range including this massive diode k=0.624.  This is not taught but my observation for the last few decades.

What are the traces on the graph?

The traces and axes are labeled, for example Rd on the left axis vs Vf on horizontal where delta V/delta I = incremental Rd ideal , dotted is more real with a 1 Ohm  bulk Resistance added, but this is a log-linear scale

do you need more info? @OskarSkog

This is the only accurate explanation of an ideal Silicon diode.

Caution: it may be racist to use the word "Shockley" do to his later work on the normal probability density function.  Just refer to the "ideal diode equation."

Thanks @richard1941
I don't think his name or his work is racist, although he was. That was an era, when living conditions promoted what we now call the Dunning-Kruger effect. I too recall the Eenie meanie toes.

@D.A.S  In science there are some questions one dare not ask or investigate... if you know what's good for you.  Remember: we are mere practitioners and suffer under the mercy of the HR managers.  Making them happy is more important than quality workmanship or truth.  They have the power to destroy us. The engineering challenge is to do this without killing anybody.

As noted, the forward drop of the diode is a logarithmic function of current, so it does not have a "threshold voltage", per se.
The LTspice sim below of a common 1N4001 diode clearly shows this:
Note that it starts conducting current at a very low forward voltage, but at a very low current.


Your diode is stronger than your AC source.
Your diode can pass more current than your AC source can provide.

As I noted from my simulation, an ideal diode only has a 0.7V drop at a particular current, and varies with current. there's nothing magic about that value, it's just the typical voltage at common diode typical low current levels in a circuit.

The power of concepts

I am asking for a fundamental and physical explanation of why, not formulas.

I would term such an explanation "conceptual". It involves extracting the most general concept from the observed phenomenon, one that is independent of the specific implementation but holds true for a wide range of cases. Using this "universal key", we can explain any specific circuit, whereas a specific explanation is limited to that particular circuit.

Physically, what is stopping the full 5 V from developing across the diode in forward bias but in not reverse bias?

In this specific instance, we need to elucidate why, at a certain point, the voltage across such a "magical" component ceases to change as you have described metaphorically.
Basic idea

Somehow in forward bias, this device magically limits the voltage to some threshold, but also if I apply more voltage the resistance keeps dropping to allow more current.

You have come very close to finding the answer to your question and merely require confirmation.
This "magical property" of voltage stabilizers (all types of diodes and other devices capable of maintaining a constant voltage) can be referred to as "dynamic resistance". It can be explained quite simply using only Ohm's law:
When the current increases, the dynamic resistor decreases its resistance at the same rate of change and vice versa. As a result, the product of current and resistance (V = IR) remains constant.
We can illustrate this by powering two such 1 V voltage stabilizers with the same current (since this is a conceptual circuit, I have used an "ideal" diode with an "exact" voltage of 1 V for simplicity). When we change the current, the voltage across them remains 1 V.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
CircuitLab experiments
Let's verify this experimentally using CircuitLab. It is sufficient to pass three values of current through a diode, a "static" resistor (for comparison), and a dynamic resistor.
Diode
By setting the current through a 1 V "ideal" diode to 1 mA...

simulate this circuit
... 2 mA...

simulate this circuit
... and 4 mA...

simulate this circuit
... we confirm what we already know: the diode maintains a 1 V constant voltage across itself.

Note: It is inconvenient that CircuitLab places the current on the x-axis, whereas it is customary to plot it on the y-.
Static resistor
Now let's try to do the same with a 1 kΩ resistor. Again, we are convinced of something we know from textbooks - the voltage across the resistor changes proportionally to the current (Ohm's law) and is 1 V...

simulate this circuit
... 2 V...

simulate this circuit
... and 4 V.

simulate this circuit

Dynamic resistor
Unfortunately, CircuitLab's library does not have such a conceptual element but we can simulate it by manually changing the resistance of a variable resistor. Three values are sufficient.
Iin = 1 mA, R = 1 kΩ: Initially, as above, 1 mA creates 1 V across 1 kΩ.

simulate this circuit
Iin = 2 mA, R = 500 Ω: But when the input current increases two times, the dynamic resistor decreases its resistance two times, and the voltage does not change (remains 1 V).

simulate this circuit
Iin = 4 mA, R = 250 Ω: Similarly, when the current increases four times, the resistance decreases four times and the voltage remains the same 1 V.

simulate this circuit
In the graphical representation, the IV curve of the dynamic resistor rotates clockwise so that its intersection with the IV curve of the input current source draws the horizontal IV curve of the resulting "diode".

Conclusion
Forward-biased diodes maintain a constant voltage across themselves by dynamically changing their static resistance (R = V/I) in the opposite direction of current changes.

It all depends what you mean by "significant", and what you mean by "ideal". In middle school radio/electronics course (around 1953, no girls allowed) we were taught that a diode has zero resistance in the forward direction, and infinite resistance in the reverse direction. As such, there is no power dissipation.  (Where can I buy one of those?)
A more realistic diode model is a bit more complicated.  Start by replacing the zero/infinite resistance model with the Shockley equation to create a perfect semiconductor junction diode.  Then add inductance, capacitance, leakage resistance, and series resistance. to the above perfect diode for something you can buy in the diode store.
If your diode is a semiconductor junction, and is in a dark place, there is an equation due to William Shockley (brilliant Nobel prize winning investigator of a certain mathematical function that is it's own Fourier transform).  Shockley gives a relationship between carrier mobility, temperature, voltage, and current.   (This information actually allows you to use a diode as a temperature sensor or voltage regulator.)  Shockley equation is
I = Is e ^ (V q / n k T) - 1, where
Is  is the forward saturation current,
q   is the charge on one little electron,
V   is applied voltage,
n   is related to charge mobility and depends on material used (silicon, germanium, gallium arsenide, etc.),
k  is Boltzman's constant.
T  is temperature (Kelvin)
For most of us, solving circuits with such a diode in series with a resistor and a voltage or current source requires iteration. You will save a lot of trouble by using the bisection algorithm instead of the usual solvers. For experts, however, there is a way to solve the diode equation directly; to learn how do do this, study the Lambert W function (which any decent calculator like the WP-34s has built in).
Keep learning.  You will never get there... but you can get closer.  I may check myself into the Radio Museum and put myself on display.  ;-)
. . . K6YVL

After a few days without comment, I thought I'd try another analogy.
What prevents the level of water behind a dam, or in a glass, from rising above the lip of the dam/glass? It's not that water can't rise, it can, it's just that you'd have to fill the reservoir/glass at a rate exceeding the rate that the dam/glass overflows.
Equating water level to electrical potential, a diode is just an electrical "dam". Charges require 0.7eV of energy for them to flow over a "potential barrier" of 0.7V , but when they do rise to the height of that barrier, they overflow to the other side unimpeded. The only reason potential on the source side of the barrier does not rise beyond 0.7V is because any charge at that level (or slightly above) will immediately flow unimpeded over the barrier.
To raise potential there significantly above 0.7V would require an incredibly low impedance source of a ridiculous number of charges, able to source enough charges per second to "fill up the reservoir" faster than those charges can escape over the edge.
The limit to how fast charges can escape over the barrier is chiefly electrical resistance. If you are able to raise the voltage across a silicon diode significantly beyond 0.7V, it will be due to parasitic resistances within the diode's various conductive elements, not the diode's inherent "dam-like" behaviour as described by the diode equation.
